# VB.net - Check SQL Field to see if Bit is Set

Tags: sql, vb.net

There is a bit field in my SQL table that I need to update to 1 if it's set at 0. I have the code written to set the field for every entry, but I need to check to see if it's at 0 already first so I can log what is changed.

Here's what I have already:

```
Public Function Update_User_to_TR(ByVal strUserName As String) As String

    Dim myUserName As String = strUserName.Trim
    Dim myReturn As String

    Try

        Dim sql As New SQL
        Dim strQuery As String

        strQuery = "Update dbo.USERS set user_field_Department_TR = 1 where USER_NAME = '" & myUserName & "'"
        myReturn = sql.SQLUpdateWT(strQuery)

    Catch ex As Exception
        myReturn = ex.ToString
        MsgBox(myReturn)
    End Try

    Return myReturn

End Function
```

Comment: Not relevant to your question but very important - go read [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) right now.  We'll wait.  Sql Injection is a very bad thing.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?  If 2005 or newer, you could add "user_field_Department_TR = 0" to the where clause then use the OUTPUT clause, like UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ... OUTPUT inserted.<whatever fields you need to log> INTO LogTable.  Note the LogTable needs to be defined ahead of time.

Comment: Why not read the value in a separate query before setting it?

Comment: -It's SQL 2005- I'll give that a go, Mr. Reband.
-Andrew- I'll try that if Mr. Reband's idea isn't working for me. 
-I'll read the entire thing, Dan. It's an intranet site....I know, it can still get attacked. It's how my supervisor set things up. Hopefully I can enact some change.

Comment: If `myUserName` happened to be "John O'Connor" it would break the query, let alone any deliberate attempt at SQL injection, just to point out how fragile it is at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to a stored procedure or a function, in this case, but here is a sample query.

```
"Declare @WillUpdate bit;Set @WillUpdate = 0;" & _
"If Exists(Select user_name from dbo.Users where user_name ='" & myUserName & _
"'        and user_field_department_tr = 0 " & _
"    Begin " & _
"      Update dbo.USERS set user_field_Department_TR = 1 where USER_NAME = '" & myUserName & "';" & _
"    Insert Into MyLog(field1, field2) " & _
"     Values('sampledata', 'field was updated from 0 to 1');" & _
"    End"
```

But please read the other comments and learn about sql injection and how it's bad, then learn how to use parameterized queries such as with ADO.NET.